# Where can I find the API documentation of the class Input?

Tags: keras

Where can I find the API documentation of the class `keras.layers.Input`? I couldn't find it at https://keras.io/.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That documentation is really hard to go through when you're not used to Keras.

But there are two approaches for building keras models:

- The `Sequential` model
- The `Model` functional API

The `Input` layer is not used with the `Sequential` model, only with `Model`.

Probably, there is no clear documentation because the `Input` layer does absolutely nothing except defining the shape of the input data to your model. (In fact it creates a "tensor" that you can use as input to other layers).

Imagine you are creating a model taking batches with MNIST data, which has 28x28 pixel images. Your input shape is then `(28,28)` (see `*`).

When creating your model, you use `Input` just to define that:

```py
#inp will be a tensor with shape (?, 28, 28)
inp = Input((28,28))
```

The following layers will then use this input:

```py
x = SomeKerasLayer(blablabla)(inp)     
x = SomeOtherLayer(blablabla)(x)    
output = TheLastLayer(balblabla)(x)
```

And when you create the model, you define the path that the data will follow, which in this case is from the input to the output:

```py
model = Model(inp,output)
```

---

With the `Model` api, it's also possible to create ramifications, multiple inputs and multiple outputs, branches, etc.

In case of having multiple inputs, you'd create several `Input` layers.

See here for more advanced examples with actual layers: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

---

`*` - This is not a rule. Depending on how you format your input data, this shape can change. There are models that prefer not to care about the 2D information and use a flattened image of shape `(784,)`. Models that will use convolutional layers will often shape the input data as `(28,28,1)`, an image with one channel. (Usually, images have 3 channels, RGB).

---

### Arguments to the `Input`

The code for the `Input` method is defined [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/topology.py/#L1377) (December, 22 - 2017)

Possible arguments:

- **shape**: defines the shape of a single sample, with variable batch size (as shown above)
- **batch_shape**: explicitly define the size of the batch in the passed shape
- **tensor**: instead of passing an input shape to the model, pass an existing tensor, you can for instance pass a tensor populated with values, such as a `K.variable()`.
- Other arguments: `name`, `dtype` and `sparse`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find the tensorflow has some API about keras. Does those `tf.contrib.keras` equal the `keras`, for example, `tf.contrib.keras.layers` equals `keras.layers`?

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras

Comment: I have no idea :(

Comment: This is a great answer. One clarifying question: I have seen examples with Input(shape=(None,256)), or Input(shape=(256,)).  I understand the None to be a placeholder, but don't understand the differences when None is first vs second (vs third, ...), or how that dimension is eventually resolved.  Is there an explanation for this part somewhere?

Comment: `None` is a variable size dimension. The shapes depend entirely on what you intend to do with your data. If you create `Input(shape=(None,256))`, internally you will have a placeholder with shape `(?,?,256)` - variable batch size, variable second dimension (usually length or time steps) and 256 elements in the last dimension (usually channels or features). Usually, this is done in data with "length", like time sequences, 1D convolutions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the things have been summarized by the above answer. But as mentioned in the comment, I think the `tf.contrib.keras` contains docs about `keras`. [This](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/layers/Input) link contains documentation for the same.

As mentioned in the accepted answer, `Input` can be used with `model` to denote the tensor. It, in fact, returns a tensor. The way I understand it is, it is somewhat similar to `tf.placeholder` as it allows us to define the model in terms of the `Input` object alone and fit the model later on. The following is the example from the tensorflow docs.

```
# this is a logistic regression in Keras
x = Input(shape=(32,))
y = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(x, y)
```

It can be seen here how the usage of `Input` is somewhat similar to that of `tf.placeholder`